# App crashes without displaying error (Retrofit 2)

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, gson

I'm learning retrofit and I'm just trying to convert the json to gson. Maybe it's because I'm not familiar with the structure of the json format of the link. I've tried another link with simpler format and the app works. I wanted to query what is inside the "data". I'm hoping you could give me some advice and figure out what is wrong. By the way, I made separate apps for these 2 links. But the process is similar.

Here is the link that I should be working :

[Link that makes app crash](http://isteward.tastradedev.com/api/organizations?type=json)

Here is the link given by the tutorial

[working link](http://pratikbutani.x10.mx/json_data.json)

Here is my Interface:

```
public interface HTTPService {

@GET("/organizations?type=json")
Call<Organization> getMyJSON();
```

}

Here is my client:

```
public class HTTPClient {
private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://isteward.tastradedev.com/api";

/**
 * Get Retrofit Instance
 */
private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

/**
 * Get API Service
 *
 * @return API Service
 */
public static HTTPService getApiService() {
    return getRetrofitInstance().create(HTTPService.class);
}
```

}

Here is my MainActivvity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView listView;
private View parentView;

private ArrayList<Datum> datalist;
private ListAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    datalist = new ArrayList<>();
    parentView = findViewById(R.id.parentlayout);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Fetching Data");
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    dialog.show();

    //Creating an object of our api interface
    HTTPService api = HTTPClient.getApiService();

    Call<Organization> call = api.getMyJSON();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Organization>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Organization> call, Response<Organization> response) {
            //Dismiss Dialog
            dialog.dismiss();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                datalist = response.body().getData();


                adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, datalist);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Organization> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

I've generated the classes using jsonschema2pojo.
The link consists of 3 classes. I guess it would make my post too long. Thank you for helping.

EDIT: I guess I have to include my adapter

Here are some parts of my adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Datum> {
ArrayList<Datum> datalist;
Context context;

private LayoutInflater inflater;


public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Datum> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    datalist = objects;
}

@Override
public Datum getItem(int position) {
    return datalist.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder vh;
    if (convertView == null) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        vh = ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
        view.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: try to debug your response from server using okhttp  HttpLoggingInterceptor.

Comment: There must be a log cat entry in the Android Monitor. Please paste it here, we need to examine it.

Comment: here Call<Organization> you are getting Organization from server, but api shows that it is child. if you generate classes from jsonschema2pojo then use Example class . like Call<Example>

Comment: @DivyeshPatel Thanks for the explanation sir. I understand it now. But how can I get the data in the "Datum" class because there are no processes in "Example" class unlike "Organization" class that has "getData()" ?

Comment: your json is nested, so use whole json as response using Call<Example>, after that , at datalist = response.body().getData();  use datalist = response.body().getOrganisation.getData();

Comment: @DivyeshPatel that is a very clear explanation for a beginner like me. thank you sir. Please answer my question so I can mark it as an answer if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all when you are using retrofit please follow below

```
http://isteward.tastradedev.com
```

please provide retrofit only the domain after that should go in the interface like this

```
@GET("api/organizations?type=json")
```

and please don't add any slashes after root url

```
http://isteward.tastradedev.com

@GET("/api/organizations?type=json")
```

And also i have seen some empty strings in you response. please convert them to null or pass something else (this might be your problem).

Comment: That did the trick!. I made the values I don't need to null then I made my baseURL to just "http://isteward.tastradedev.com". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My reputation does not allow me to comment your question, but can't you just convert json to string and then string to gson?

Comment: sorry sir but I am tasked to do "automatic gson"

Answer (score 0):

For getting Specific array/string you have to use parent object to getting DATA. You can not get nested array directly using that POJO. So Change api class as per below:

First make api interface that accept whole JSON from server:

```
@GET("/organizations?type=json")
Call<Example> getMyJSON();
```

Here, Example class contains getter/setter of JSON resonse.

Now, When you request API, use that class callback to get response successfully,

```
Call<Example> call = api.getMyJSON();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            //Dismiss Dialog
            dialog.dismiss();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

      /*** HERE response.body contains whole JSON, you need to pass through whole chain to get desire Data. SO Organization class conatains DATA so use it like***/

                datalist = response.body().getOrganization().getData();;

       /--- datalist  is list of Datum array list. now pass that to adapter ---/

                adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, datalist);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: In addition to the code sample please add description so people with similar issues can get context by reading your hints.

Comment: Still crashes. When I traced the flow of the code, it should work. I really don't know what's making the app crash.

Comment: The problem was with the baseURL sir. but I think it was the combination of your solution and @MaxExplode. Thank you to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problam **"App crashes without displaying error"**
but i had following issue:

i forgot including `@Body` at parameter:

```
@Headers({CACHE, AGENT})
@POST("api/check/info")
Call<CallbackInfo> checkInfo(
    Info info
);
```

and problam solved by adding `@Body`:

```
@Headers({CACHE, AGENT})
@POST("api-v1/check/info")
Call<CallbackInfo> checkInfo(
    @Body Info info
);
```